# Como obtener resultado completo de INNER JOIN en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

he buscado y me trae loco este asunto, resulta que necesito realizar un inner join entre dos tablas en rails, pero este me devuelve solo el resultado de la tabla inicial:

```
Metodo 1

Clase.joins(:Alumno)

Metodo 2
@todo = Clase.joins("INNER JOIN alumnos ON clases.alumno_id = alumnos.id")

Metodo 3
@todo = Clase.joins("INNER JOIN alumnos ON clases.alumno_id = alumnos.id").select("*")
```

En todos me devuelve solo el contenido de la tabla Clase que tiene coincidencia con la de Alumno, pero no me devuelve la cadena completa de ambos resultados.

Comment: Consultas que hagas con tu modelo `Clase` solo te traerá atributos que pertenezca a esa clase, por tanto no incluirá atributos de `Alumnos`. Si lo que quieres es no realizar N+1 queries, podrías probar con [`Clase.includes(:Alumno)`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Yo lo unico que necesito es traerme los resultados que estan en ambas tablas que coicidan mediante "clases.alumno_id = alumnos.id" como podria hacer?

Comment: Deberías iterar tu arreglo `@todo` y por cada elemento `Clase`, revisar los `.alumnos` que tiene. Ahora, si quieres traer todo en una única consulta, puedes hacerlo, pero deberías hacer la consulta a mano y ya se escapa del alcance (o la utilidad) de ActiveRecord. Insisto, con `.includes` debería bastar para lo que requieres, lo cual te hace un `JOIN` internamente.

Comment: Al parecer no tengo las claves primarias creadas, imagino, porque ni con include lo toma, como es el metodo de interar?